# usb 3-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110

Tags: startup

I cannot start my laptop.  I was trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,  but suddenly it could not boot.

it just tells me

```
[ 18.900478] usb 3-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, but suddenly got the same boot error:

```
usb 3-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

As far as I understood this error says about malfunction of USB power supply.
But the main issue is near NVidia graphic driver [Cannot install Ubuntu 15.10 on Dell Precision M6800](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701558/cannot-install-ubuntu-15-10-on-dell-precision-m6800)

I've tried to boot Ubuntu 14.04 from live CD, all was OK. So I desided to roll back to 14.04.